# TensorFlow XOR implementation, fail to achieve 100% accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensor

I am a newbie in `machine learning` and `tensorflow`. I am trying to implement XOR gate in tensor flow I have come up with this code.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

learning_rate = 0.01
n_epochs = 1000
n_inputs = 2
n_hidden1 = 2
n_outputs = 2

arr1, target = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1,1]], [0, 1, 1, 0]

X_data = np.array(arr1).astype(np.float32)
y_data = np.array(target).astype(np.int)


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None), name="y")


with tf.name_scope("dnn_tf"):
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_outputs, name="outputs")

with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch: ", epoch, " Train Accuracy: ", acc_train)

        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X:X_data, y:y_data})    
        acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X:X_data, y:y_data})
```

The code runs fine but I am getting different outputs in each run

Run-1

```
Epoch:  0  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  100  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  200  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  300  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  400  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  500  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  600  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  700  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  800  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  900  Train Accuracy:  1.0
```

Run -2

```
Epoch:  0  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  100  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  200  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  300  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  400  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  500  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  600  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  700  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  800  Train Accuracy:  0.75
Epoch:  900  Train Accuracy:  0.75
```

Run3-

```
Epoch:  0  Train Accuracy:  1.0
Epoch:  100  Train Accuracy:  0.5
Epoch:  200  Train Accuracy:  0.5
Epoch:  300  Train Accuracy:  0.5
Epoch:  400  Train Accuracy:  0.5
Epoch:  500  Train Accuracy:  0.5
Epoch:  600  Train Accuracy:  0.5
Epoch:  700  Train Accuracy:  0.5
Epoch:  800  Train Accuracy:  0.5
Epoch:  900  Train Accuracy:  0.5
```

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong here and why my solution is not converging.

Comment: Increase hidden layer size and 1000 epochs on dataset as small as this is not necessary. Also you  want to have one neuron at the end, right?

Comment: But number of training example is only 4. I thought 1000 epochs will be enough to converge. Apology if my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps the network is just too small, have you tried with higher n_hidden?

Comment: Yes with n_hidden=5 it's converging lot faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it's possible to solve XOR with one hidden layer with two units with ReLU activations as you have in your code. However, there is always the crucial difference between a network being able to *represent* a solution and being able to *learn* it. I would assume that due to the small size of the network you run into the "dead ReLU" problem where due to unfortunate random initialization one (or both) of your hidden units doesn't activate for any input. Unfortunately ReLU also has zero gradient when it has zero activation, so a unit that never activates also cannot learn anything.

Increasing the number of hidden units makes it less likely that this happens (i.e. you can have three dead units and the other two will still be enough to solve the problem), which could explain why you are more successful with five hidden units.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the interactive [TensorFlow Playground](https://playground.tensorflow.org/). They have a XOR dataset available. You can play around with the number of hidden layers, size, activation functions etc. and visualise the decision boundaries the classifier learns with the number of epohcs.